# Validating a select option list through jQuery custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a custom validation function at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/dc7rmsjw/) but it is not working. Here is the code I have:

```
$(function () {
     function selectInput(elem) {
         inputData = $.trim(elem.val());
         if (inputData == "na") {
             $('error').html('Please Select From The List');
         } else {
             return inputData;
         }
     }
     $("#pro").on("click", function (e) {

         if (selectInput($('#uselect'))) {
             alert('Correct Selection');
         } 
         else{console.log("There is an Error! But Where?!")}
         e.preventDefault();
     });
 });
```

and HTML is

```
<form>
    <select id="#uselect">
        <option value="na">Choose...</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="pro" />
</form>
<div id="error"></div>
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your ID for the select

```
<select id="#uselect">
```

It has a `#` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Loose the # in

```
<select id="#uselect">
```

Use

```
<select id="uselect">
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `#` in your `select` tag:

```
<select id="uselect">
```

As a side note, you should not use global variables if possible, so change:

```
inputData = $.trim(elem.val());
```

to

```
var inputData = $.trim(elem.val());
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have "#" in your id , so manage that

then you will Either get 1 ot 2 as value not

```
   value="1" 
   value="2"
```

if nothing selected then you will get "na"

Answer (score 0):

I stopped it by removing the function implementation from your DOM-Ready event like so...

```
 //DOM-Ready Event Listner
 $(function () {
     $("#pro").on("click", function (e) {
         if (selectInput($('#uselect'))) {
             alert('Correct Selection');
         } else {
             console.log("There is an Error! But Where?! Bahh"); //<--Added a ';'
         }
         e.preventDefault();
     });
 });

 //Separated Implementation
 function selectInput(elem) {
     inputData = $.trim(elem.val());
     if (inputData == "na") {
         $('error').html('Please Select From The List');
     } else {
         return inputData;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> [**Working Demo jsFiddle**](http://jquery.demo.free.fr/jsFiddle/?id=1)

You're missing a character: add a "#" in:

```
$('error').html();
```

like this:

```
$('#error').html();
```

and remove "#" in:

```
<select id="#uselect">
```

like this:

```
<select id="uselect">
```